# Salesforce1 Where are these action buttons defined?

Tags: salesforce1-app

[image]

My Salesforce1 view of an Account is as above, in the browser /one/one.app. I don't know where some of the action buttons (the 5 icons at the bottom) are coming from.

The second and third icons are the "Edit" and "Delete" buttons on the page layout. By removing them from the page layout, I can make them disappear from here.

The first, fourth and fifth icons are

- Call or Log
- Map
- Read News

and I've no idea where they are coming from. The "Publisher Actions" section of the Page Layout is empty. If I add an action to it, it appears in addition to these five. If I add "Mobile Smart Actions" it adds a lot of actions to these five.

I don't think they're Global Actions. I changed the label of the "Log a Call" global action and it made no  difference to this display. And there's no "Read News" Global Action listed. There aren't any custom links on the Page Layout.

I'd like to know where they come from so I can see if it's possible to hide or replace them. The "Call or Log" button has a nice feature that calls the phone number, but when logging it doesn't obey my redirect on Task.Log a Call link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Admin Guide these are called as record actions and you cant add or delete them

[image]

You can read this in newly found salesforce 1 Admin guide

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1appadmin/salesforce1_admin_guide.pdf

Comment: As of Summer '15 you are able to customize the Salesforce1 action bar and move or remove these actions -- see http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_actionbar_customization.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce Lightning Setup Page:

User Interface > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts

Here you can assign/customize layouts for the action bar buttons.